# function doesn't detect EOF

Tags: c

Function get_word is supposed to read word from stdin and save it. Saving next word after white char and return EOF on EOF but I am still getting in infinite loop. htab_lookup_add is some function to save word into table. There also seems to be a problem "Too long message" never prints but that's not the problem I am trying to solve now.

```
int get_word(char *s, int max, FILE *f){
    s = malloc(sizeof(char) * max);

    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = getc(f))){
        if(i > max || isspace(c)){
            break;
        }
        s[i++] = c;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

    if(c == EOF){
        return EOF;
    }
    return i;
}


while(get_word(word, (maxchar + 1), stdin) != EOF){
    if(strlen(word) > maxchar){
        printf("Too long!\n");
    }
    htab_lookup_add(table, word);
}
```

Comment: There are too many bugs in this snippet. Please post a [mcve] that focuses on one problem.

Comment: For example, `get_word` ignores the first argument passed in (`word`) and allocates a new buffer (`s`) that leaks when the function returns.

Comment: `get_word` writes outside the bounds of `s`. The valid indices are from `0` to `max-1`. If there is no whitespace character or `'\0'` in the input, the function will write to `s[max]` and `s[max+1]`.

Comment: If `get_word` returns in the middle of a word (because `max` was exceeded), it loses an input character.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
while((c = getc(f))){
    ...
}
```

will terminate only when `getc()` returns zero, i.e., when it reads a null character `'\0'`. And when it returns `EOF` you'll store that value (converted to `char`) in `s[i]` and continue looping.

The test for `EOF` *after* the loop will never match.

You need to end the loop when it returns `EOF`. The usual idiom is:

```
while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes but this will only make EOF end the word. This is the reason why break in isspace condition is used. I seems that I can get out of function cycle but I cannot get out of the cycle where I am using the function.

Comment: @Maraz: The condition on the loop is wrong. It needs to check for `getc(f)` returning `EOF`, not `0`. You can also have a conditional `break` statement that will break out of the loop in other circumstances.

Comment: I was thinking about this function and I ramade it. Hopefully it is better and with no much buggs, but should I edit (change whole post) or post another question?

Comment: @Maraz: Post another question if you still have problems. Don't modify your existing question in a way that invalidates existing answers.